# Get user name from the command line on different platforms

Tags: matlab, platform-independent

Is there a way in MATLAB to get the user name of the user that started the session?

I am interested in solutions for **Windows**, **Linux** and **Mac OSX**. I imagine that if the solutions are platform-specific, both solutions can be integrated as follows:

```
if ispc
    user_name = % method 1
elseif isunix
    user_name = % method 2
elseif ismac
    user_name = % method 3
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if isunix
    [~, user_name] = system('whoami') % exists on every unix that I know of
    % on my mac, isunix == 1
elseif ispc
    [~, user_name] = system('echo %USERDOMAIN%\%USERNAME%') % Not as familiar with windows,
                            % found it on the net elsewhere, you might want to verify
end
```

Hope that helps!  You might want to also put in a `else I'm confused` clause just in case you do find that system that is not unix nor pc.

Answer (score 13):

How about using Java (works on all platforms supported by MATLAB):

```
user_name = java.lang.System.getProperty('user.name')
```

Comment: Definitely the more portable/elegant/reliable solution.

Comment: Not surprisingly, this will not work if `matlab -nojvm` is run from the command line.

Comment: Also might have to enclose in `char(user_name)` to cast to a typical matlab char array for `sprintf`, `switch` statements, etc.

Answer (score 1):

To get it on Windows:

`getenv('USERNAME')`

Comment: How about a bit more detail.